# Monte-Carlo: R script not returning anything

Tags: r

My R script is

```
mcnorm.R <- function(M,N)
{
library("mvtnorm", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.2")
R <- as.matrix(read.csv("Data.csv", header=FALSE))
mu <- colMeans(R)
sigma <- cov(R)
r <- array(0,dim=c(M,ncol(R),N))
for(n in 1:N)
  {
    r[,,n] <- rmvnorm(M,mu,sigma)
  }
}
```

It is a Monte-Carlo simulation of N matrices of multivariate-normal data of sample size M, where the dimension is determined by the data set.

But when I call

```
> data <- mcnorm.R(12,10)
```

I get that the data is empty.  Why isn't my code returning anything?

**Edit**:  Defining a global variable by including

```
 r <<- r
```

before the last curly bracket seems to work.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't return anything because you don't give the function a value to return.

You assign a bunch of stuff to a local variable, but your function doesn't know to return it.

You either need to have an unassigned expression at the end of your function (which is then the value of the function), or to explicitly use `return`.

contrast these two functions:

```
f1=function(x) x+1    # returns a value
f2=function(x) x=x+1  # assigns a value, doesn't return anything
'f1';f1(1)
'f2';f2(1)
```

Now try this:

```
f2=function(x) {
   x=x+1  # assigns a value
   x      # then gives an expression to return
}

'f2';f2(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The original question is answered by Glen_b but there seems to be another problem. You set `M` but it has to be determined from your data by `nrow(data)`. Below is a quick adaptation.

```
set.seed(1237)
data <- matrix(rnorm(10 * 2), ncol = 2)
mcnorm.R <- function(data, n) {
  require(mvtnorm)
  m <- nrow(data)
  mu <- colMeans(data)
  sigma <- cov(data)

  lapply(rep(m, n), function(x) {
    rmvnorm(x, mean = mu, sigma = sigma)
  })
}

mcnorm.R(data, 2)
[[1]]
[,1]       [,2]
[1,]  0.56329623  0.4190237
[2,] -0.22289337 -0.9868659
[3,]  0.15122364  0.4912512
[4,] -0.02535081 -1.6834980
[5,]  1.55228756  0.6220963
[6,]  1.92250690  0.8586562
[7,]  0.74490463  0.8905072
[8,]  0.58680482  2.1364250
[9,] -1.77529229  0.9194059
[10,] -0.31811879  0.5085753

[[2]]
[,1]       [,2]
[1,]  0.2651033  0.9444386
[2,]  1.6429256 -0.8526075
[3,]  0.2551873  0.6049124
[4,] -0.3276499  0.9374114
[5,]  0.5807373 -2.9733458
[6,] -0.5385768 -0.8017294
[7,]  1.1536321 -0.7026208
[8,]  0.1487368  2.7005468
[9,] -1.8679594  0.7792719
[10,] -0.1405379  0.7594246
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I don't want my simulations to have the same number of rows as the data set.  The data set is only being used to estimate the mean and variance-covariance matrix.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. Still it may be necessary to take out `R <- as.matrix(read.csv("Data.csv", header=FALSE))` from your function as data may be changed or unavailable. It seems to cause side effects. It is not easy to include another argument anyway?

Answer (score 1):

I think that Glen-b's answer partially misses the point: the problem with that function is that the user has to declare

```
r <- array(0,dim=c(M,2,N))
```

in the global environment, i.e. outside the function mcnorm.R.